# Cannot find function newDataValidation Gscript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to google script and finding difficulty to use newDataValidation function in google script.

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1A2B3C");   
  var cell = sheet.getRange("H2").getValue(); //EX 9190
  //Logger.log(cell); 
  var rule = sheet.newDataValidation().requireNumberBetween(1, 100).setAllowInvalid(false).setHelpText('Number must be between 1 and 100.').build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
}
```

> Error : TypeError: Cannot find function newDataValidation in object Spreadsheet. (line 5, file "validate")

Comment: Error : TypeError: Cannot find function newDataValidation in object Spreadsheet. (line 5, file "validate")

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.openById` returns `Spreadsheet`, and `newDataValidation` function is available in [`SpreadsheetApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newdatavalidation)